# How to get sum of many cells that are linked to one cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a query that returns the total cost of the items sold on an invoice. I have tried all sorts of sum, and case methods but can't get the logic behind it.

```
select 
    Concat(invoiceNum, '-', invoiceSubNum) as 'invoice',
    itemCost                                     
from tbl_invoiceItem 
group by 
    invoiceNum, invoiceSubNum, sku, 
    itemCost, itemPrice, itemDiscount, 
    percentage
order by invoiceNum
```

The data that it currently outputs:

```
 Invoice | itemCost
 1-1     | 60
 1-1     | 5
 2-1     | 25
 3-1     | 10
 3-1     | 5
```

What I want it to output:

```
 Invoice | totalCost
 1-1     | 65
 2-1     | 25
 3-1     | 15
```

Would creating a #temp table be a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SUM` all the cost in the invoice

```
select 
    Concat(invoiceNum, '-', invoiceSubNum) as 'invoice',
    SUM(itemCost)
from tbl_invoiceItem 
group by 
    Concat(invoiceNum, '-', invoiceSubNum)
order by invoiceNum
```